# React native app with downloadable plugins?

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

I wanted to make an app with react native that acts as a hub for different services or plugins. Each plugin can be downloaded, incorporated into the app and executed. I've seen solutions like codepush that allow you to change the code of the app, but I think it only allows you to change the whole code of your app, and not change it based on the services that you have downloaded. 
I would really appreciate some help or guidance through this, since I'm not even sure it can be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea, but you always may eval any code. So feel free to download your plugins in a string format and eval them afterwards.

Comment: @Kirill I've been trying to use eval, but so far I haven't been successful. eval throws errors when executing jsx code. Even if that code was transpiled first with babel,I still haven't gotten it to work